# Issue with $PATH and .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos

So I was installing flutter the other day and somehow I guess I messed a bit with my profile files. The issue i'm facing is that whenever I echo my PATH var it  gives me the "I have no idea where did I add these"

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

while my .bash_profile has the paths added

> export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
>   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
>   export PATH="$PATH:/Users/raeedasif/development/flutter/bin"[image]

So basically what I'm facing is that when I type echo $PATH it gives me the undesired PATHS while if i use the command ( basically source it )

> source ~/.bash_profile

it gives me the desired outcome that is PATHS in picture above, especially the flutter one, please help me fix my profiles on my machine

Thanks every one!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210372/discussion-on-question-by-raeed-asif-issue-with-path-and-bash-profile).

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would probably check, is /etc/profile, which AFAIK is the system wide default/template profile for bash.

Comment: cant figure it out, there is no profile folder in etc , while ther eis a text file name profile in etc , which i dont really understand.

Comment: @RaeedAsif : The name of the folder is `/etc`. The file name is `profile`. But I would recommend against the suggestion of petrus4, unless you want to ensure that your settings should apply to all users.